# Question about Static methods

Tags: java

The question asks for the user to enter. lets forget about that and make it already initialized with some values so I can understand the first part.

> Write a static method
>   `public static int findMax(int[] r)`
>   which receives as a parameter an array of numbers of type int and returns the maximum value.
>   Write a main method to test your program with array size 10 and elements entered by user.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Show us what you have so far and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int findMax(int[] values) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int val : values) {
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Max value: " + findMax(new int[]{1,2,3,1,2,3}));
}
```

Comment: -1 for being duped into doing someone's trivial homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much I tried to compile it but I'm getting `class, interface, or enum expected`

Comment: @duffymo It's not trivial, I always forget the array syntax `new int[]{1,2,3,1,2,3}` :)

Comment: @Mohammad Fadin That's because everything in Java must be inside a class, interface and enum and this is not. There are some Java tutorials on the net, go and have a look there.

Comment: what is the array name in this? is it max or findmax?

Comment: @Mohammad Fadin: you have to write this inside a class......There is no name for an array in this example. `findmax` is method name and `max` is a temporary variable taken to keep track of max value in an array.

Comment: @extraneon oh! I looked and I watched videos but I keep seeing people using `private xxx` `private xxxx`  and in my textbook there is no mentioning about that that is why I don't know how to solve static examples.

Comment: Thank you again guys my main problem was creating class I didn't know I have to do that because I just kept solving and messing without using main class, I'll post my solutions for other examples after I do them. I want to shut that guy up who keep saying HW HW HW.  i'm not doing a HW! i'm trying to learn here!!

Comment: Question: what does `for (int val : values)` mean?

Comment: @Mohammad: it's foreach loop. That means looping over `values` array getting its elements one by one in `val`.

Comment: It's the Java 'new'-style for loop, or for-each loop. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: [The Java Tutorial Language Basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) has the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @thasc @Harry Joy   Oh I see. I'm trying to convert them to for loop but I keep getting  `.class expected`

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I managed to solve 2 other questions based on the help you provided. I noticed that this Static Method is the same Static Method I learned before 5 years in FORTRAN 75 language. Remembering this opened my mind again. TY so much here is a question I just solved http://bit.ly/jTgQHd

Answer (score 3):

Can't get what you exactly want to do? But if want that one class has static method and other class in main access that then you can try like this..

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = FindMaxClass.findMax(new int[10]); // pass int array
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}

class FindMaxClass{
    public static int findMax(int[] r){
        //logic to find max.
        return 0; // return the max value found.
    }
}
```

If static method should be in same class then others answers are good/correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the code to solve your *exact* problem, but I'll tell you how to create and call a static method.  See the example below:

```
public class Test {

    // This is a static method
    static void myMethod(int myArg) {
        System.out.println("Inside Test.myMethod " + myArg);
    }

    // This is how to call it from main()
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more information to static methods take a look at:

http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/javainsel/javainsel_05_003.htm#mjd51d5220468ee4a1f2a07b6796bb393b

But you already know how to iterate over arrays?

Or maybe you are able to be more specific what you do not understand and what you have tried yet?